# Outlook 2010 "Mark item as read when selection changes" ONLY in Inbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, email-filter

I would like my Outlook 2010 To "Mark item as read when selection changes" ONLY in the Inbox. When I view messages in other folders I want this behavious to be disabled.

I have a Rule that moves all my "engineering" emails to an "engineering" folder, and I want to manually "Mark as read" those email, but I want all my other "Inbox" emails to automatically mark as read after I view them. I hope that makes sence...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. This option is Outlook-wide.